# Как открыть предпросмотр при одновременном редактировании кода storyboard?

Tags: swift, xcode, autolayout, preview

Как открыть предпросмотр верстаемой странички в XCode одновременно с редактированием ее кода как текста? В Android Studio это выглядит примерно так:

[image]

Здесь я могу вживую наблюдать за тем, как мои изменения в коде влияют на отображаемый интерфейс. Когда я пытаюсь открыть две вкладки на одном экране в XCode (одна с Preview, другая с кодом той же самой страницы соответственно) - то у меня всегда открывается только одна.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Preview работает только для storyboard и xib, в икскоде 11 и версии ОС Catalina для проектов на SwiftUI вы можете открыть справа аналог Preview под названием Canvas